# Why it would be better keeping track of #Reference than #PID when implementing a GenServer?

Tags: elixir, gen-server

Elixir's [Mix and OTP Guide Chapter GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html) explains how to implement a registry server holding agents, using `GenServer`.

Each agent's PID is kept in a map, where the keys are the agent's names given by the clients and the values are the agent's PIDs.

In order to avoid keeping references to dead agents, the guide proposes monitoring newly created agents using `Process.monitor/1` and slightly modifying the state by adding a new map, called `refs`, containing References (values returned by `Process.monitor/1`) as keys and agents' names as values. It also shows how to handle monitoring messages using `handle_info/2` to update `refs`.

`Process.monitor/1` receives a PID (e.g. `#PID<0.66.0>`) as a parameter and returns a Reference (e.g. `#Reference<0.0.0.551>`). The `:DOWN` message caught by `handle_info/2` provides both the PID and the Reference.

Since we know all the time both values: What are the benefits of using References as keys over using PIDs in `refs`, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a matter of consistency. While you have only processes monitored, there is no difference. But underlying [`:erlang.monitor/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) can monitor not *only* processes: there are ports etc, that basically have no `PID`.

From the doc:

> • `Object`
>
> The monitored entity, which triggered the event. When monitoring a local process or port, `Object` will be equal to the `pid()` or `port()` that was being monitored. When monitoring process or port by name, `Object` will have format `{RegisteredName, Node}` where `RegisteredName` is the name which has been used with `monitor/2` call and `Node` is local or remote node name (for ports monitored by name, `Node` is always local node name).

The summing up: `Reference` is an entity, being monitored. It might be a process, a port, whatever. While you do not want to [`demonitor/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#demonitor-1) the whole process that closed the port monitored, you should use references.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to just remember the PID, if you just have a small project and *only* want to monitor some processes. But I would recommend to use the Reference, because Projects grow fast and you may want to monitor not only processes. Elixir uses underneath the `:erlang.monitor/2` which also let you monitor `ports` and a `time_offset` between Erlang monotonic time and Erlang system time. This can be found in the [Docs here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) The Reference is more generic and is a better practice to use the Reference in general.

Here a small example what I want to say:

```
iex(1)> :erlang.monitor(:time_offset, :clock_service)
#Reference<0.0.3.100>

iex(2)> :erlang.monitor(:process ,self())
#Reference<0.0.3.113>
```